# Copying database tables to new database

Tags: database, migration, plugin-wpml

am trying to migrate my old site to a new site, by only copying database tables. the reason doing this way is the old site is out of date with plugins etc and i have WooCommerce installed which i dont have translated only post/pages are in 2 languages.

After iv copied over the tables when i went to pages/post it shows 0, yet WooCommerce shows all. iv ran through your WPML troubleshooting to fix any errors etc… this seems to work! but it now shows all pages but not under any lang!

How can i can copy this correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export your tables using phpmyadmin interface. Just select those tables only that you want to export from the old database and import those tables in the new database

or you can run the command(query) in mysql to copy one table

```
create table newdbname.newtablename like olddbname.oldtablename;
INSERT INTO  newdbname.newtablename SELECT * FROM olddbname.oldtablename;
```

Repeat the same command to copy other tables